# Twitter Bot how can i get callback url

Tags: api, rest, twitter, bots

This is my first attempt to make a bot application on twitter

but there are some requirements to connect api and i don't understand..

there need callback url, where can i get callback url?
can it use localhost?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will only need a functional callback URL if you plan on building an app that users will log in to. If you already are able to get the access token and key for your bot account then you can use `http://localhost` in the callback URL field.